# Does Android uninstall complete clean up?

Tags: android, uninstallation, resource-cleanup

If I uninstall Android app via Applications manager from device, will system uninstall it **completely** without leaving any leftovers?
We're experiencing some issue with behavior of our Android app, where tablet has to be rebooted between uninstall of old version and install of new version or after installation of new version. Thanks.

Comment: What issue you are facing ?

Comment: it's one of our customers and issue is really weird. App plays HLS streams where quality should switch among three profiles, LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH, based on bitrate. And issue is that it stays at LOW and doesn't switch at all to better quality. It's a 3rd party player, integrated.

Comment: It should be issue with the 3rd party player code which you have integrated.

Answer (score 0):

Application data directory will be completely deleted after uninstall. But if the app store some data on sdcard or on gallery, it will not get removed. User can store data backup Using [Data Backup service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html)  which can be restored later .If a user performs a factory reset or converts to a new Android-powered device, the system automatically restores your backup data when the application is re-installed.